# Google Maps ­not showing up

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API. I directly copied [the example code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async) from the docs but the map isn't showing up the way I expected:

[image]

I tried to look through my code to see if there's any error, but no luck. Any idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/B3KYB/ (The key is removed)

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map($("#mapView")[0], mapOptions);
}
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('mapView')` instead of using jQuery.

Comment: @RobH - I'm not really returning a jQuery object in my code. But I did tried changing it to native method, and yet the problem is still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS:

```
div, body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

...will affect any div-element in the page, also the div's created by the maps-API.

Use this selector instead: `#mapView, body, html`

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/nmwHw/

Comment: +1 Cool, I got it in fiddle.  When I came back I saw your answer.  I would like to add this, css should be like `#mapView {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
`

Comment: Oh! Didn't know why I didn't catch that in the first place, thanks!